# Split the first and second part of list of list into two sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am facing an issue given below and I want to separate the 0th element and the 1st element in two separate lists. for eg I have a list

```
a = [[1, 2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
```

I want two lists like:

```
a0 = [1,3,5,7]
a2 = [2,4,6,8]
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt and what result you got with your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
a = [[*x] for x in zip(*a)]
print(a[0], a[1]) # [1, 3, 5, 7] [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
a = [[1, 2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
a0 = []
a2 = []
for i in a:
    a0.append(i[0])
    a2.append(i[1])

print(a0)
print(a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
a = [[1, 2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
a0 = [x[0] for x in a]
a2 = [x[1] for x in a]
print(a0)  # [1, 3, 5, 7]
print(a2)  # [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1, 2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
a0 = []
a1 = []

for x in a:
    a0.append(x[0])
    a1.append(x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

use chain to flatten the list, then calculate the middle index, then split it into two lists from the middle index

```py
In [1]: from itertools import chain

In [2]: a = [[1, 2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]

In [3]: flat = list(chain.from_iterable(a))

In [4]: flat
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [5]: middle = len(flat) // 2

In [6]: first_half = flat[:middle]

In [7]: second_half = flat[middle:]

In [10]: first_half
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [11]: second_half
Out[11]: [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
import numpy as np    
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
np.array(a).T.tolist()
```

gives as

```
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```